# in labelimg, reopening the app resets classes.txt

Tags: labelimg

I have a folder containing 1000 photos. And I tagged 100 photos with **labelimg**. In three classes: "car", "motorcycle" and "truck". But every time I open the **labelimg**, the previous tags are deleted from "***classes.txt***" and there is only the new tag that I created. And when I open the previous tagged photos in the **labelimg**, it gives ***list index out of range*** error and then **labelimg** will closed.

the error:

```
label = self.classes[int(class_index)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

### How can I have previous classes each time?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Label Studio, it is much better than labelImg

Install the packege:

```
pip install -U label-studio
```

Lunch it!

```
label-studio
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the paths for the images folder and classes.txt

If you have build from source: 
`python labelImg.py [IMAGE_PATH] [PRE-DEFINED CLASS FILE]`

If you have pip installed labelImg:

`labelImg [IMAGE_PATH] [PRE-DEFINED CLASS FILE]`

where: 
`[IMAGE_PATH]` is the path to your images folder 
`[PRE-DEFINED CLASS FILE]` is the path to the folder that has your predefined `classes.txt` and the annotation txt files

Example: `labelImg C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\images C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\Labels\classes.txt`

Comment: This is indeed the correct solution